# Error trying to download content with PrimeFaces <p:fileDownload> java.io.IOException: Error in streaming dynamic resource Exception

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello fellow programmers. I'm tryin to use `<p:fileDownload>` in a JSF app with PrimeFaces 10. I want to download a plain data file (not a graphic or image), which is fetched from the database as a byte array.

In the view I have the download button:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
    <p:commandButton value="Descargar..." 
                     rendered="#listaMaterialesBacking.listaSeleccionada.nombreArchivoDiseno != null}">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{listaMaterialesBacking.descargaDiseno}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

In the (view scoped) Managed bean I have:

```
@Named(value = "listaMaterialesBacking")
@ViewScoped
public class ListaMaterialesBacking implements Serializable {
...
    public StreamedContent getDescargaDiseno()
    { 
        //we fetch the byte array from the db
        byte[] archivoD = getListaMaterialesFacade().recuperarArchivoDiseno(listaSeleccionada.getId()); 
        
        StreamedContent file = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                                .name(listaSeleccionada.getNombreArchivoDiseno())
                                .contentType("application/octet-stream")
                                .stream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(archivoD))
                                .build();
    
        return file;
    }
}
```

Then when I click in the download button, the browser replies with a 15KB file download that has inside HTML code than contains inside:

> Error processing request Context Path: /obrasttt-1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> Servlet Path: /faces
>
> Path Info: /javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties
>
> Query String:
> ln=primefaces&v=10.0.0-RC1&pfdrid=471e3b498e52f03eee44242c8050ee23&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=62d196e9-84c2-455e-81b7-c089f53b80f6
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> java.io.IOException: Error in streaming dynamic resource at
> org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler.handle(StreamedContentHandler.java:120)
> ...

Files stored in the DB are not very large, these are like 500kB size.

I'm using:

Primefaces 10.0.0-RC1.jar

JDK 1.8

JSF 2.3 (mojarra)

Wildfly 25

MySQL 5.7

Apache NetBeans 12.4

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are using [Ajax downloading](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/filedownload?id=ajax-downloading), which uses [dynamic content streaming](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/dynamiccontent), which [does not support `@ViewScoped`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/dynamiccontent?id=viewscoped-support).

For a working example, see the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml).